# Specify source port range with curl using PHP

Tags: php, curl, port, php-curl

I need to specify the source port range for curl.
I don't see any option who let me choose a range for source port in TCP.

Is it possible?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Why do you want to connect to a range of ports?

Comment: There is a firewall who block curl traffic if the source port is below 20000... Is have no time to wait for the network guys ;)

Comment: But what do you mean by connecting to a range of ports? A TCP connection only connects to a single port...

Comment: Curl have to use a port inside a specific range e.g. 30.000 to 65535

Answer (score 4):

You can use `CURLOPT_LOCALPORT` and `CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE` options, which are similar to curl's `--local-port` command line option.

In the following example curl will try to use source port in range 6000-7000:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOCALPORT, 6000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOCALPORTRANGE, 1000);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

From the command line one would use:

```
curl --local-port 6000-7000 <url>
```

For documentation see: [CURLOPT_LOCALPORT](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_LOCALPORT.html) and [Local port number](https://everything.curl.dev/usingcurl/connections#local-port-number).

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better using `fsockopen`. I came up many times this worked for me when blocked by firewalls. See: http://php.net/fsockopen

```
$ports = array(80, 81);
foreach ($ports as $port) {
    $fp =@ fsockopen("tcp://127.0.0.1", $port);
    // or fsockopen("www.google.com", $port);
    if ($fp) {
        print "Port $port is open.\n";
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        print "Port $port is not open.\n";
    }
}
```

By the way, there is `CURLOPT_PORT` for CURL, but doesn't work with `tcp://127.0.0.1`;

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://127.0.0.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 80);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$re = curl_exec($ch);
// echo curl_errno($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print $re;
```

Comment: CURLOPT_PORT is normally for the distant port : CURLOPT_PORT  An alternative port number to connect to.

Comment: They are asking to set the port for the connection to connect **from**, not **to**.